# Json serialized data having backslashes

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, response

I am using rest_framework.response method to send objects of multiple django models. However, the response containts backslashes with quotes. Here is my view:

```
@api_view()
def myfunctions(request,id):
    responseData = {}
    userObject = TifUser.objects.filter(id=id)
    attendances = Attendance.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    leaves = Leave.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    odds = ODD.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    printjobs = PrintJob.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    issues = Issue.objects.filter(User=userObject)

    #serialize into json
    userObject = serializers.serialize("json", userObject)
    attendances = serializers.serialize("json",attendances)
    leaves = serializers.serialize("json",leaves)
    odds = serializers.serialize("json",odds)
    printjobs = serializers.serialize("json",printjobs)
    issues = serializers.serialize("json",issues)

    #set responseData dictionary values
    responseData['user'] = userObject
    responseData['attendances'] = attendances
    responseData['leaves'] = leaves
    responseData['odds'] = odds
    responseData['printjobs'] = printjobs
    responseData['issues'] = issues
    #responseData['attendances'] = userObject
    return response.Response(responseData)
```

The json response I am getting is:

```
{"attendances":"[{\"model\": \"mainApp.attendance\", \"pk\": 5, \"fields\": {\"ArrivalTime\": \"2016-06-27T18:45:46.355Z\", \"DepartureTime\": null, \"User\": 4, \"ArrivalImei\": \"1\", \"DepartureImei\": null, \"Hash\": \"321f059c-4230-417a-adff-f0035097c85d\"}}, {\"model\": \"mainApp.attendance\", \"pk\": 13, \"fields\": {\"ArrivalTime\": \"2016-07-18T15:40:39.943Z\", \"DepartureTime\": null, \"User\": 4, \"ArrivalImei\": \"2\", \"DepartureImei\": null, \"Hash\": \"e61fad3e-8238-46fc-b09b-8b7754d43f3b\"}}]","printjobs":"[{\"model\": \"mainApp.printjob\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"User\": 4, \"DateAdded\": \"2016-07-18\", \"Status\": \"disapproved\", \"Person\": 5, \"Level\": \"boss\", \"Client\": \"someone\", \"HandledBy\": \"tester\", \"SanctionedBy\": \"myself\", \"AdvancePayment\": 0, \"FinalPayment\": 1000, \"PaymentNumber\": 1, \"Remarks\": \"something\"}}]","odds":"[]","user":"[{\"model\": \"mainApp.tifuser\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"AuthUser\": 7, \"Head\": null, \"Boss\": null, \"ClrLevel\": 1, \"Department\": 1, \"DesignationName\": 1, \"Name\": \"tester\", \"IsRegistered\": true, \"DateOfBirth\": \"1222-11-11\", \"Anniversary\": \"2001-12-22\", \"Mobile\": \"2134567890\", \"gcmDevice\": null, \"FatherName\": \"\", \"MotherName\": \"\", \"PersonalEmail\": \"\", \"Gender\": \"Male\", \"CurrentAddress\": \"\", \"PermanentAddress\": \"\", \"PANNumber\": \"\", \"AadharCardNumber\": null, \"BloodGroup\": \"\", \"MaritalStatus\": \"Married\", \"ProfilePhoto\": \"\", \"Imei\": \"\"}}]","leaves":"[]","issues":"[]"}
```

Is there any other way to do it? What I understand is, it is encoding the data twice (once in serializers.serialize and then in response.Response). But I dont want that. I want nested objects. Something like this:

```
{"attendances":[{"model": "mainApp.attendance", "pk": 5, "fields": {"ArrivalTime": "2016-06-27T18:45:46.355Z", "DepartureTime": null, "User": 4, "ArrivalImei": "1",...
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you `print` your json response, are the backslashes gone?

Comment: @ShangWang yes, there are no backslashes while printing. It's only in the response that I am getting them.

Comment: Then you are getting json string which escapes the quotes. Can you do `result = json.loads(json_response)` and see if `result` is a data structure that you want?

Comment: @ShangWang that also shows backslashes.

Comment: try to return like this, return response.Response(serializers.serialize('json' ,responseData))

Comment: Can you try to do: 

`return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseData), content_type='application/json')`

Comment: @RanaAhmed it shows the error: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: @SanyamKhurana no use. Similar thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you identified, you are double-serializing everything by converting your querysets to JSON strings, adding them to a dict and then passing the dict to `response.Response`.

Much of the point of using Django REST Framework is that is handles the serialization for you, so the goal should be to avoid serializing to JSON strings yourself in the api view.

To make best use of DRF you need to define a `ModelSerializer` for each of the models you want to return in the response.

One thing that is confusing in DRF is the terminology. Normally when we talk about "serialization" it means converting objects to a string (i.e. JSON). But in DRF, serializers actually convert complex objects -> primitive objects.  So when you use a `ModelSerializer` to "serialize" your queryset it does not produce a JSON string, but rather primitive python objects (a dict) that can then be serialized, in the conventional sense, to a JSON string without errors. This 'real' serialization is done for you by the `Response` class.

So I suggest as a starting point:

```
class TifUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TifUser


class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance


class LeaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Leave


class ODDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ODD


class PrintJobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PrintJob

class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue


@api_view()
def myfunctions(request, id):
    users = TifUser.objects.filter(id=id)
    user_serializer = TifUserSerializer(users, many=True)

    attendances = Attendance.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    attendance_serializer = AttendanceSerializer(attendancesv, context={'request': request})

    leaves = Leave.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    leave_serializer = LeaveSerializer(leaves, many=True)

    odds = ODD.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    odd_serializer = ODDSerializer(odds, many=True)

    printjobs = PrintJob.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    printjob_serializer = PrintJobSerializer(printjobs, many=True)

    issues = Issue.objects.filter(User=userObject)
    issue_serializer = IssueSerializer(issues, many=True)

    responseData = {}
    responseData['user'] = user_serializer.data
    responseData['attendances'] = attendance_serializer.data
    responseData['leaves'] = leave_serializer.data
    responseData['odds'] = odd_serializer.data
    responseData['printjobs'] = printjob_serializer.data
    responseData['issues'] = issue_serializer.data

    return response.Response(responseData)
```

Comment: this was what I tried to do in the beginning. But I got the following error: <Attendance: 2016-06-27 18:45:46.355095+00:00 to None> is not JSON serializable. That's why I had to do it this way.

Comment: @nikssardana what is a bit confusing with DRF is normally "serialization" means converting object to string (i.e. JSON) but DRF serializers actually convert complex objects -> primitive objects (i.e. the primitives supported by JSON format: dict, list, int, float, str). These primitive objects can then be serialized into a JSON string by the `Response` class.  So what you need is a DRF serializer that translates your Django model instances into primitive objects http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: what you want is `ModelSerializer` http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: thanks a lot for the info. Yeah I've used these before but I don't know why i didn't think about using in this case.

Comment: I used `attendance_serializer = AttendanceSerializer(attendances,many=True)`. Now I am getting an error: object is not json serializable.

Comment: what is the stack trace?

Comment: did you maybe leave out the `.data` part from `responseData['attendances'] = attendance_serializer.data`?  the stacktrace is telling you that `AttendanceSerializer` is not serializable, but it shouldn't be trying to serialize the serializer instance itself, just the result

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Also, I had to add the context as I was using a HyperLinkedModelSerializer.. It's working now. Thanks :)

Comment: @nikssardana glad you got it working! I've added the HyperLinkedModelSerializer to the answer. if you found it helpful please accept it :)

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to solve it. The problem was, when the objects were serialized using serializer.serialize() function, I was getting a string. Whereas I wanted a dict. I had to use json.loads() to convert the string into a dictionary as:

```
responseData['user'] = json.loads(userObject)
```

And everything worked as I wanted to. Now, the response is something like:

```
{
    "attendances": [
        {
            "pk": 5,
            "model": "mainApp.attendance",
            "fields": {
                "DepartureTime": null,
                "Hash": "321f059c-4230-417a-adff-f0035097c85d",
                "ArrivalImei": "1",
                "DepartureImei": null,
                "User": 4,
                "ArrivalTime": "2016-06-27T18:45:46.355Z"
            }
        },
```

Comment: it makes no sense to serialize to json, then unserialize it and add it to your `responseData` dict, then have rest framework serialize it again